# Is it possible to change directory mountpoint online?

Tags: linux, mount

Suppose I have a production server with one big root partition cotaining everything. I want to put a directory, for example `/var`, in a separate partition, along with all the data it has. The obvious way of copying all data to the new partition and then mounting it could result in data inconsistency, since changes in an online system can be unpredictable.

I was thinking of something along the lines of:

1. Mount empty partition somewhere;
2. Copy all data from `/var` to the new partition;
3. Start holding/locking (queuing?) all write requests to `/var`;
4. Sync the final changes with rsync;
5. Mount new partition to `/var`;
6. Release the lock made in step 3.

Steps 3 and 6 are what I don't know how to do.

Is something like this possible without downtime? If not without downtime, then at least with a short downtime without rebooting the server?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have already created your filesystems using LVM (and I guess you didn't because you probably wouldn't be asking this if you did) you really will struggle to do this 'online'. The /var tree for example has many daemons with log files open continuously, you will find it difficult to move these without restarting the daemon(s).

As you're pretty much going to have to restart your system you might as well just scedule a maintenance window and do it off line in single user mode where it should be as straightforward as

- rename old /var to something else
- mount the new /var
- update /etc/fstab to reflect changes
- copy data
- reboot to usual run level

Comment: I don't really see how using LVM would make this any easier. If I wanted to change the partition where data was located, it would not matter whether I was using LVM or not.
This is a hypothetical question, but to make it easier to understand, imagine that `/var` is located on a slow HDD and I need to (for whatever reason) move it to an empty SSD I have hot-plugged.

Comment: @Mythoranium: For any filesystem that 'live' processes reading/writing to it you will have to stop those processes. Move stuff and then restart them. You can't really do it 'online'.